# how to read json data in perl sent through ajax/jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, perl

I tried to do a simple mysql return on the same page, after entering a id into the html field.

I sent it through ajax to a perl script that should do a search in the DataBase and get a result of the name.

I was searching the web tried differnt options but I couldn't find the right answer for what I'm looking for.

I'm tring to get a id number send it to the database and get the name of this id contact.

Here is my html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<HTML xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
</script>
<META charset="utf-8">
<TITLE>Ajax-tool</TITLE> 
</head>

<body>
<form id="procform" name="procform" method="POST" action="">
<b>Contact ID:</b>
<fieldset>
<input type="text" id="CID" name="CID" size="20" />
<p><input type="submit"></p>
</fieldset>
</form>
<p></p>
<div id="content"></div>

<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="/js/ajax01.js"></SCRIPT>
</body>
</HTML>
```

The jQuery script:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form#procform").submit(function() {
    var id =    $("#CID").val();
    var jsondata = { 'CID' : id };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://192.168.10.1/cgi-bin/ajax01.pl",
                async: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {CID: id},
            success: function(result) {
                $("div#content").text("data.success: " + data);
                //alert(data);
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                alert(request.responseText);
            }
        });
//alert( + id + "");
    });
});
```

And the perl script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -T


use CGI ":all";
use DBI;
#use strict;
use warnings;
use Encode;
use JSON;
use Storable;
#$foo = CGI->new;



#$foo->charset('utf-8');
$json = JSON->new->allow_nonref;

$dbh = DBI->connect('mylogin)
                || die "Could not connect to database: $DBI::errstr";
#my $cidID   = CGI->new->param( 'CID' );


my $cidID   = $json->decode('CID');
#my $cidID  = $foo->param('CID');
#$cidID = 44;

#########    select contact name from contacts    ##############
$sth0 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM  contacts WHERE cid= $cidID")or "can't prepare : $DBI::errstr\n";

$sth0->execute()or die "Can't execute: $DBI::errstr\n";

@row0 = $sth0->fetchrow_array;

my $VCName3 = $row0[1];

$sth0->finish();
print $VCName3;

my $json1 = $json->encode($VCName3);

print $foo->header(-type => "application/json", -charset => "utf-8");
print $json1;
```

If I give the cidID a value inside the perl script and delete the entire definition of the head part for json, I get  the right result for the cidID.

But the problem is to get the right data into cidID from the ajax.

**UPDATE**

I'm new here so i dont know if to erase the part above or to leave it for others to learn..

however- i made a second look at the web and did some changes to the code, as an example-

in ajax i changed the method from "POST" to "GET"

right now it's working, i dont know why it isn't working with POST, any ideas?

but when i want to display the result in the DIV it just flashes for a moment and doesn't stay there.

and is there any way to get the result back in a variable for further use in jquery?
 i tried -

```
var result = $(data.userid);
```

without any succes.

here are the codes the way they work-

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<HTML xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
</script>
<META charset="utf-8">
<TITLE>Ajax-tool</TITLE> 
</head>

<body>

<form id="procform" name="procform" method="POST" action="">
<b>Contact ID:</b>
<fieldset>
<input type="text" id="CID" name="CID" size="20" />
<p><input type="submit"></p>
</fieldset>
<p></p>
<div id="content"></div>
</form>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="http://192.168.10.1/js/jquery.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="http://192.168.10.1/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="http://192.168.10.1/js/ajax01.js"></SCRIPT>
</body>
</HTML>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form#procform").submit(function() {
    var id =    $("#CID").val();
    var jsondata = { 'CID' : id };
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http:/cgi-bin/ajax01_1.pl",
                async: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "CID=" + id,
            success: function(data) {
                $("div#content").append("Name: " + data.userid);
                //alert("Name: " + data.userid);
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                alert(request.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**PERL**

```
use DBI;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Encode;
my $foo = CGI->new;
my $cidID = $foo->param("CID");

my $dbh = DBI->connect('here goes my login passw ect..')
                || die "Could not connect to database: $DBI::errstr";

my @row0;
#########    select contact name from contacts    ##############
my $sth0 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM  contacts WHERE cid= ?")or "can't prepare : $DBI::errstr\n";

$sth0->execute($cidID)or die "Can't execute: $DBI::errstr\n";

@row0 = $sth0->fetchrow_array;

my $VCName3 = $row0[1];

$sth0->finish();
print $VCName3;

my $json1 = ($VCName3)? 
  qq{{"success" : "login is successful", "userid" : "$VCName3"}} : 
  qq{{"error" : "username or password is wrong"}};;

print $foo->header(-type => "application/json", -charset => "utf-8");
print $json1;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Perl script is full of weirdness. I would recommend fixing these oddities before wondering if there might be an actual problem.

1. `use strict`. Seriously. This will point out many sources for bugs. And it forces you to declare your variables (with `my`). That is a good thing.
2. uncomment the `$foo = CGI->new`, because you actually *use* that object later on. But for that, the variable really should be initialized with an object. Also, rename it to something sensible, and declare the variable: `my $cgi = CGI->new;`. [→ monumental CGI docs](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI)
3. You forgot a quote around `'mylogin`.
4. Oh, and while you are `die`ing: Should you die, that error message ends up in your logs. That program will produce many more errors, so you should have accumulated quite some entries. Look at them maybe, and fix the problems! Also, you might want to send errors to the browser during development. Do this with `use CGI::Carp qw/fatalsToBrowser/;`. [→ CGI::Carp documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI::Carp)
5. Read the [JSON documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/JSON). Be sure that `decode` and not `decode_json` is the thing you really want (`decode_json` assumes UTF-8). Both methods want a JSON string. The Perl string `my $not_json = q/CID/` is *not* valid JSON. That would be `my $json = q/"CID"/`. See the quotes?
6. I still assume that you want to read a parameter from the POST or GET request. Once you follow hint № 2, that should work again.
7. I don't know SQL, but I know you're doing it wrong. Never ever interpolate variables into an SQL statement, or you are *inviting* injection attacks! Use parameterized statements : `my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE cid = ?') or die ...`, then execute it with the actual variable as a parameter `$sth->execute($cidID) or die ...`.
8. `$sth->fetchrow_array` fetches only one row, but you selected *all* rows. Either fix your SQL so you only select the first row, or loop over all rows! `while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array){ do something @row }`. [→ DBI docs](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI)
9. You `print $VCName3` before you printed the headers! This will likely produce many `500` errors. Don't do that.
10. You specify that your JSON is sent as `UTF-8`. Perhaps you should be using `encode_json`.

<sub>[Insert joke about ten commandments here]</sub>

After you fixed these issues, the problem may or may not remain. If it does, please update your question and drop a comment that you did so. We'll then look how we can solve those *actual* problems.

Comment: Indeed, `use strict` is *essential*. The only reason it isn't enabled by default is to avoid breaking huge amounts of legacy code: it is mandatory for anything new.

Comment: thanks for you're fast and detailed answer, i made an update of the question, thanks for any further help!